# How to deal with 'dynamic' dataframes using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have the following table

| X | Y | Z | mm | ff | cc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 0.2 | 0.4 | 0.3 |
|  |  |  | 0.1 | 0.3 | 0.4 |

which exported as a .csv file gives the following file content:

```
     X,Y,Z,mm,ff,cc
     1,2,3,0.2,0.4,0.3
     ,,,0.1,0.3,0.4
```

Now.. if the table would have only one row I can access any cell in python using pandas like:

```
    X = df.loc[0, 'X']    # X = 1
    Y = df.loc[0, 'Y']    # Y = 2
    Z = df.loc[0, 'Z']    # Z = 3
    mm_1 = df.loc[0, 'mm']  # mm_1 = 0.2
    ff_1 = df.loc[0, 'ff']  # ff_1 = 0.4
    cc_1 = df.loc[0, 'cc']  # cc_1 = 0.3
```

and if I would like to read the cells on the second row I need to change the code like:

```
    mm_2 = df.loc[1, 'mm']  # mm_2 = 0.1
    ff_2 = df.loc[1, 'ff']  # ff_2 = 0.3
    cc_2 = df.loc[1, 'cc']  # cc_2 = 0.4
```

Now... the problem is that the original csv file can have between one row and 6 rows.

Let's keep it simple. If I hard code the reading of all cells (0-1) like the code above, I'm going to have problems, when the csv file has only one line, since the variables: `mm_2`, `ff_2`, `cc_2` will not find anything.

There is a way in pandas to deal with such situations?

Comment: `df.iterrows()`?

Comment: @QuangHoang you are a genius!

Comment: Write an answer please so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `df.iterrows()` or you can also iterate through the normal loop and neglect the values which are equal to `NaN`. The NaN values are empty and filled by dataframe.